# terminal/shell/automator/applescript command to turn off bluetooth on mac

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, applescript, automator

How do I turn off `bluetooth` via `terminal`/`shell`/`automator`/`applescript` on a Mac? It should be pretty easy.

BTW, I know you can get applescript to press the `bluetooth` menu and then press `turn bluetooth off`. I don't want this if possible.

Comment: Should be moved to Super User, this is not a programming problem.  That said, see [blueutil](http://www.frederikseiffert.de/blueutil/).  It should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to use [blueutil](http://www.frederikseiffert.de/blueutil/).

-- gadgetmo

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go about it.  You can tell `launchd` to unload the Bluetooth daemon and no longer start it on demand, or you can programmatically toggle the preference for it and stop the server.

For the former method, use `launchctl` to tell `launchd` to unload the daemon and set its disabled flag:

```
# launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.blued.plist
```

If you want to restore it later, this should suffice:

```
# launchctl load -wF /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.blued.plist
```

That should do it.  Now for the latter method, first update the preference file (same thing that would happen when toggling from the UI):

```
# defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist ControllerPowerState -BOOL 0
```

Then, you can just rudely kill off the server:

```
# killall blued
```

Later, you can restore the preference by resetting the bit:

```
# defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist ControllerPowerState -BOOL 1
```

Then kick launchd to have it fire up `blued` again:

```
# launchctl start com.apple.blued
```

Comment: Dunno if this answer ever worked, but there are multiple things wrong with it.  First of all, it should be "-bool NO" or "-bool YES".  "-BOOL" (uppercase) and "1" or "0" are all invalid arguments.

Second, you need to use sudo: `sudo launchctl start com.apple.blued`.  Better to use explicit path: `sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.blued.plist` and `sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.blued.plist` .

Finally, that pref doesn't actually seem to set whether Bluetooth is on or not.  At least not on Lion.

Comment: @SimoneManganelli Consider posting your information as a full-fledged answer, or suggest an edit to Spencer's answer.